# Is it viewport issue or what?

Tags: viewport, mozilla, tablet, device-width

Body takes window sizes as planned, but if I click on mousewheel in Mozilla Browser or just scroll right/bottom in ipad I've got this margins. I assume that this happening because of some content, which first appears in document and then hides, but may be not that... How may I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Btw, I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` in `<head>`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should give the CSS [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property a try:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```